# makecert.exe - parameter list for -ss option?

Tags: makecert

I want to put my certificate into specific store, but I don't now the name of this store as the parameter for the -ss option of makecert.exe. Where I can find all the possible parameters for each option of this tool? Neither MSDN nor -? (help option for the tool) can help.

For example, what is the -ss equivalent for the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"? And another certificate stores also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a list of store names at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx. Use the value in the "Member Name" column under the "Members heading". Note that not all certificate stores may be available in all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the `cert:` drive in PowerShell.  Just `cd cert:`.  Windows8/Server 2012 has `Import-PfxCertificate`.